# Teen boy going into some virtual reality place (Christian novel, late 90s')

Tags: story-identification, virtual-worlds, christian

I vaguely remember reading this when I was a kid. It was probably around the same section as the Frank Peretti 'Cooper Kids' series. It would have been a series of 'Christian' teen novels.

My recollection was that the main character was a boy around 13. His father had some shiny device that, when he touched it(?), he was able to be transported into this virtual reality. He meets a girl in there, I remember they described her eyes as blue or green with "gold flecks".

The lesson of the stories was basically that God can intervene even in the split nanoseconds of processing of the [computer] running the VR to save the boy.

The books would have been published around the mid/late 1990s.
I've searched and searched but can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've found it.
It's a trilogy, the first book is called [*A Race Against Time: A Novel* (Virtual Reality, Book 1)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0785279237) by William Kritlow.
I've ordered it off Amazon and eagerly await it to share with my kids.

> In this first book in the Virtual Reality series, a brilliant scientist experimenting with recombinant DNA develops a deadly virus and accidentally infects himself and several others. Before falling into a coma, he informs his brother that the formula--and the cure--are hidden inside a virtual-reality computer program. The brother contrives to blackmail the world by threatening to release the virus and then sell the cure. First, however, he must find the formula. Morty Craft, a retired FBI computer specialist, is hired to solve the mystery of the deadly outbreak of disease. Aided by his teenage niece and nephew, he explores the quirky computer world to find the formula before the evil brother does. By overcoming a series of obstacles designed to test one's spiritual resolve, the trio finds the formula, just in time. Despite the lackluster title and the moralizing tag-on about "True Reality" versus virtual reality, this is fascinating fare for young computer literates.

Edit: I previously thought I’d found it as: The series called *Cyber Quest* by Sigmund Brouwer

It was not. That was a lone first book we had on the shelf as a child. I tried to read and enjoy it, but couldn’t.